# Adobe Illustrator: Export PDF (custom preset) + Export JPG (RGB) 300dpi quality 10

Tags: adobe-illustrator, save, illustrator-scripting, script

I work a lot of graphics daily and at the end of the work i always save in two different formats: PDF Print Ready & JPG (RGB) 300dpi > Quality 10

So everytime i do have to make this steps:

- 1) CTRL + A > Select all elements from all artboards
- 2) CTRL + SHIFT + O > Create Outlines
- 3) CTRL + SHIFT + S > Select PDF (Note: if there is a file with same name i always overwrite)
- 4) Select Preset: PDF/X1a:2001)
- 5) Go to Marks & Bleeds > Select checkbox: "Use documents bleed and settings"
- 6) Hit Save
- 7) Go File > Export
- 8) Select JPG
- 9) Check box "Use Artboards" (leave "All" selected as standard, no change here) Note: if there is a file(s) with same name i always overwrite
- 10) Select Color Mode "RGB"
- 11) Quality 10 (maximum)
- 12) Options: Baseline (Standard) + 300 dpi + Type Optimised (Hinted)
- 13) Click "Ok"

After this process i will end with:

- 1x PDF File (all artboards inside separated by pages)
- All JPG files separate files per artboard.

I would like to know if there is available a script that replicates this kind of steps at once (multiple sabe actions) since its always this same process i use? Or something very similar so i can try an adaptation?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can record an action.

Go to Windows>Actions
Create a new Set and within that create a new action.

Then follow all the steps you usually take, I would record this with a generic file first. In a convenient save location, for example in Windows, in the Documents folder.

The PDF and JPG will save as the same name as the illustrator file and in the location where you specified when you recorded the action. You can then move the files to where ever you need to store them.

You can also set a keyboard shortcut to the action before recording.

Comment: Hey Aasim Azam, thank you so much for this. Its absolutely awesome and worked perfectly. Only one question: is not possible at all to make this as its working now but the files to be saved to the folder where the .ai source file is already located instead of a generic folder? to avoid the "cut/paste" of the files to the correct folder of each .ai file?

Comment: Unfortunately you can't, if this was a ode based action, you'd edit the code to do this, but unfortunately Adobe doesn't support this.

Comment: @AasimAzam your last statement is not true. Adobe dows support this just not recording to code. but thats not a big problem you can still call the action.

Comment: @joojaa so its possible to save the files in the same folder as the source file is saved/located?

Comment: @graphic.ninja yes you just have to type the script yourself.

Comment: oh, ok.... won't be able to do it, lol. the action will have to do for now :) thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a SINGLE pdf file and download the software [here](https://www.tracker-software.com/product/downloads)

Open the file in the software
file > Export > Export to Image
You can select the image type JPG, PNG,etc